# Unexpected behavior on AJAX query

Tags: javascript, ajax, request, xmlhttprequest

I do some requests to update database without reloading, but I have some weird behaviors on my requestion.

Here is my code

```
jQuery("#question1").click(function () {
  jQuery.ajax({
    //L'URL de la requête 

    var nbvues = jQuery("#count1").text();
    alert(nbvues);
    url: "/php/sky-forms-pro/countfaq.php?id_faq=1&nb_vues=" + nbvues,
    //La méthode d'envoi (type de requête)
    method: "GET",
    //Le format de réponse attendu
    dataType: "json",
  })
    //Ce code sera exécuté en cas de succès - La réponse du serveur est passée à done()
    /*On peut par exemple convertir cette réponse en chaine JSON et insérer
    * cette chaine dans un div id="res"*/
  .done(function (response) {
    let data = JSON.stringify(response);
    jQuery("#count1").html(data);
  })

  //On peut afficher les informations relatives à la requête et à l'erreur

});
```

This show me a weird mistakes, I don't know where I'm wrong:

[image]

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? the problem is that you are adding var into object that is passed to jquery ajax. It's a syntax error

Comment: I want to submit this var for the ajax request in order to update the database. I need to take the value of a span which is a number, then I incremente it and update database it's a kind of view counter

Comment: $.ajax is a function and that function expects an object as a parameter(and you are passing an object), but the object format is not correct. Object should be key value pair.

Comment: So change `var nbvues = jQuery("#count1").text();  alert(nbvues);` to `data: {count1:jQuery("#count1").text()},`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can read in the [jquery.ajax](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) documentation:

> Data to be sent to the server. If the HTTP method is one that cannot
> have an entity body, such as GET, the data is appended to the URL.
>
> When data is an object, jQuery generates the data string from the
> object's key/value pairs unless the processData option is set to
> false. For example, **{ a: "bc", d: "e,f" }** is converted to the
> string "**a=bc&d=e%2Cf**"

```
jQuery("#question1").click(function () {
    var nbvues = jQuery("#count1").text();
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: "/php/sky-forms-pro/countfaq.php",
        method: "GET",
        data: {
            id_faq: 1,
            nb_vues: nbvues
        },
        dataType: "json"
    }).done(function (response) {
        let data = JSON.stringify(response);
        jQuery("#count1").html(data);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much, since my last time using ajax or coding something was in 2010, I did know the answer but I was not able to see this. I really appreciate your help